# having trouble with path with css background-image: url(/pathto/img/bg.jpg);

Tags: css

background image isn't showing up I have in main.css

```
body {
    background-image: url('/../img/background.jpg');
}
```

my file paths are

C:/pathTo/css/main.css and 
C:/pathTo/img/background.jpg

thanks for any help

Joel

Comment: Are you using a webserver?

Answer (score 2):

```
body {
    background-image: url('../img/background.jpg');
}
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Try without the first backslash.

```
body {
    background-image: url('../img/background.jpg');
}
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of Kevin Harrison's answer! only its nearly 2 minutes later.

Comment: I opened it in a new tab and I didn't refresh before answering.

Comment: Ahh so thats why - Thats worth making a note of. Thanks.